# :onchange event causing loop thru method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, axios

I have an application made with Vue.js, this application is making several post requests with Axios. In one of my components i have a table and a selectbox. The selectbox contains several 'tutorgroups' for example '4M07a'. Every tutorgroup has a bunch of students that i need to display in the table. I achieved this by doing a :onchange event and sending the selected value to my method. In my method i am doing a post request with axios with the selected value, teachername and the apikey. The problem is that the :onchange event is cause a loop thru my method. When i look into the network tab in DevTools i just see unlimited requests being made. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

I tried using different event handlers and putting a return inside my method but nothing has worked so far.

My selectbox:

```
<select v-model="selectedValue" :onchange="getStudents(this.selectedValue)" class="select-klas form-control">
    <option> Selecteer een tutorgroep </option>
    <option v-for="(tutorklas, index) in tutorklassen" :key="index">{{ 
    tutorklas.id }}</option>
</select>
```

My method:

```
getStudents(event) {
            // zet data klaar om verzonden te worden
            const postTutorClassData = new FormData();
            postTutorClassData.append('docent', this.teachername)
            postTutorClassData.append('apikey', this.apikey)
            postTutorClassData.append('tutorgroep', event)

            // maak post request naar API
            axios.post(this.URL_TUTORKLAS, postTutorClassData)
            .then((response) => {
                this.docenten = response.data.docent;

                this.leerlingen = response.data.leerlingen;

                // force stop
                this.selectedValue = 'null';

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

It is not giving any error messages, it just keeps looping thru my method.

Comment: Wrap your onchange in a function:

`:onchange="()=>getStudents(this.selectedValue)"`

Comment: @WillJenkins For some reason it is not getting into my method at all this way. it gives back this error message: 'Unexpected token ('

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:onchange` is not the correct syntax to listen for a change event in vue, you also don't need to pass this.selectedValue into the method as it will be available in your data (you don't have access to `this` in a template).

Try the following:

Change `:onchange` to be:

```
@change="getStudents"
```

Update your `getStudents` method to:

```
getStudents() {
    const postTutorClassData = new FormData();

    postTutorClassData.append('docent', this.teachername);
    postTutorClassData.append('apikey', this.apikey);
    postTutorClassData.append('tutorgroep', this.selectedValue) // remove event and use selected value

    axios.post(this.URL_TUTORKLAS, postTutorClassData).then(response => {
        this.docenten = response.data.docent;
        this.leerlingen = response.data.leerlingen;

        // this.selectedValue = 'null';
        // Changing this to be null will re-trigger the change event, causing your infinite loop
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

Comment: It's working now, thank you! the reason i had null as a string was because i was forcing the loop to stop by giving it a invalid value for the post, now that i think about it i could've just said null instead of making it a string like you said haha.

Answer (score 1):

use @change instead of :onchange